# Updating Redis with external query result from multiple machines

Tags: caching, transactions, locking, redis

I have a setup where with 2 web server and a central redis server and a SQL server.

I need to use redis as a cache for queries made against the SQL server.

So the web server will check the redis cache first, before going to the SQL server and cache that result.

However the 2 web servers don't know that the other exists, so they cannot replace a "newer" cached result.

I want to avoid this scenario:

TIMELINE:

- WebServer1 : Checks redis for a key, and no result is found.
- WebServer1 : Queries the SQL sever for Result1.
- WebServer2 : Saves new data to SQL server, that changes the query result.
- WebServer2 : Invalidates the Redis key.
- WebServer2 : Queries the SQL sever for Result2.
- WebServer2 : Puts the Result2 in the Redis Key.
- WebServer1 : Puts the Result1 in the Redis Key.

The problem above is the newest result "Result2" is overwritten by "Result1".

Is there anyway to avoid this in Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a lock that holds off any other queries until you're done querying/updating redis from some server. Set a very low timeout on this, so you don't block for too long.

If you're on Redis 2.6.12+ you can use the [SET locking pattern with Lua](http://redis.io/commands/set) for this.
If you're on an earlier version, you can use the [SETNX locking pattern](http://redis.io/commands/setnx).